# How to Split String With double quotes in java

Tags: java, split

This question is Pretty Simple

How to Split String With double quotes in java?,

For example I am having string  **Do this at "2014-09-16 05:40:00.0"**,After Splitting, I want String like

```
       Do this at 
       2014-09-16 05:40:00.0,
```

Any help how to achieve this?

Comment: _Have you tried anything?_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This way you can escape inner double quotes.

```
    String str = "Do this at \"2014-09-16 05:40:00.0\"";
    String []splitterString=str.split("\"");
    for (String s : splitterString) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Output

```
Do this at 
2014-09-16 05:40:00.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method `String.split()`
It returns an array of String, splitted by the character you specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "Do this at \"2014-09-16 05:40:00.0\"";

        String parts[] = test.split("\"");
        String part0 = parts[0];
        String part1 = parts[1];
        System.out.println(part0);
        System.out.println(part1);

    }
```

**output**

```
Do this at 
2014-09-16 05:40:00.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Maybe it can help

```
String str = "\"2014-09-16 05:40:00.0\"";
String[] splitted = str.split("\"");
System.out.println(splitted[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided thus far simply split the string based on any occurrence of double-quotes in the string. I offer a more advanced regex-based solution that splits only on the first double-quote that precedes a string of characters *contained* in double quotes:

```
String[] splitStrings = 
    "Do this at \"2014-09-16 05:40:00.0\"".split("(?=\"[^\"].*\")");
```

After this call, `split[0]` contains `"Do this at "` and `split[1]` contains `"\"2014-09-16 05:40:00.0\""`. I know you don't want the quotes around the second string, but they're easy to remove using `substring`.